# How to split one long columns into multiple columns shell script

Tags: shell

I have a sequence of value in one column that I would like to split in multiple columns.
The number of rows is known only number of columns is changing.

Here my input :

```
,
0,
3.375,
1,
21,
BEAM
-7.1,
,
1,
-100,
0,
0,
,
0,
,
2,
3.7375,
1,
0,
,
0,
,
0,
9.375,
1,
29,
BEAM
-7.9,
,
1,
-100,
0,
0,
,
0,
,
2,
3.7375,
1,
0,
,
0,
```

Desired output where number of columns is 2:

```
,          ,
0,         0,
3.375,     9.375,  
1,         1,
21,        29,
BEAM       BEAM,
-7.1,      -7.9
,          ,
1,         1,
-100,      -100,
0,         0,
0,         0,
,          ,
0,         0,
,          ,
2,         2, 
3.7375,    3.7375,
1,         1,
0,         0,
,          ,
0,         0,
```

What I tried 1st :

```
NUMBER=$(cat HBS-A | cut -d"," -f1 | sed '/\--/d' | uniq | wc -l)
pr -ts" " --columns $NUMBER HBS-value | tr -s " " "," | sed 's/^,//' > HBS-table
```

First, I determine how many sequence are in the file to get the number of columns.
THen I use `pr` command, it works beautifully but when the number of column is limited to 72.
Most of the time I have more than 100+ columns.

Then I tried this :

```
awk -v row=21 '{A[(NR-1)%row]=A[(NR-1)%row]$0" ";next}END{for(i in A)print A[i]}' HBS-value
```

It will give the right format but all my data is completely scrambled and I don't understand why but
when I try with a simple example such as:

```
A 
B
C
D
```

I would get :

```
A C
B D
```

Any suggestion please ?

EDIT-----

This is my output from the example above :

```
0,          0,
0,          0,
,           ,
0,          0,
0,          0,
,           ,
2,          2,
3.7375,     3.7375,
1,          1,
0,          0,
,           ,
,           ,
0,          0,
3.375,      9.375,
1,          1,
21,         29,
BEAM        BEAM
-7.1,      -7.9,
,           ,
1,          1,
-100,      -100,
```

`BEAM` is supposed to be row #6 but it goes to #17

Comment: 1. Get the first half of the file. 2. Get the second half of the file. 3. Join using `paste`.

Comment: @KamilCuk in the case where I have 2184 lines, one sequence is 21 lines, I would need 104 columns. Should I use a loop to cut in half with PR until I reach  the final size ?

Comment: Wait, wait. You presented a file that should generate two columns. So cound of columns must be predefined, given?

Comment: @KamilCuk approach is still viable, I think. You just have to generate as many files as the columns, and then join them with `paste`.

Comment: The count of columns is determined by the number of lines.

Comment: How is the count of columns calculated? `one sequence is 21 lines` - so the count of rows is given? And the count of columns is count of lines in file divided by 21 ? @edit .... because `2184/21 = 104`.

Comment: One sequence is 21 lines, if I have for example 2184 lines of values, then I would need 104 columns.

Comment: look at the "pr" formatting utility

Comment: @KamilCuk yes the count of row is fixed to 21 and yes I do divide by 21 the total number of line to get the number of columns.

Comment: @mpez0 pr is limited to 72 columns

Comment: `but all my data is completely scrambled` - that `awk` script is nice and works fine for me. I guess that your input file has dos line endings, please check. That would explain the "scrambled" output. Output the file with `cat -v file` and inspect the output

Comment: I check if there is DOS ending line but there is not, and I checked `cat -v file` and it gives the same output.  The output scrambled in the way where the row order is completely mixed up but columns are consistent (with expected data)

Comment: if I had DOS ending line, I should expect the same results with `pr` ? But with `pr` I don't face issue with mixed output @KamilCuk

Comment: Then I think the only case is when you give us an [MCVE] with the sample input that generates "scrambled" output. For example like `seq 2184 | awk -v row=21 '{A[(NR-1)%row]=A[(NR-1)%row]$0" ";next}END{for(i in A)print A[i]}'` works for me as expected.

Comment: @KamilCuk I did the update and show the output I have from my example to illustrate my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manager to get rid of the limit by adding `-w LIMIT`, I will put `5000` just to be on the safe side.

So in my case that would be :

```
NUMBER=$(cat HBS-A | cut -d"," -f1 | sed '/\--/d' | uniq | wc -l)
pr -ts" " --columns $NUMBER HBS-value -w 5000 | tr -s " " "," | sed 's/^,//' > HBS-table
```

Answer (score 2):

There is utility [`columns`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-columns/#lbAF) that is part of `autogen` package on my archlinux, that let's you just specify the count of columns with `-c` option:

```
columns --by-columns -w 1 -c $(( $(wc -l <file) / 21 )) -i file
```